# Xcode Error: Could not instantiate class named _UIScrollViewLayoutGuide

Tags: xcode, ios9

I am running my Xcode project (Xcode 11) on an iPhone 4S running iOS 9 and I am getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named _UIScrollViewLayoutGuide'

I have tried looking up solutions to this error but could not find any. My code has installed all constraints and am suspecting it is because I am using the Interface Builder to create the scroll view.

What is odd is that other scroll views in the app are working fine, but this one keeps giving me this error… Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I have found an answer! I am unsure why Xcode did not flag the error in the first place. With the new Xcode support for iOS 13, ScrollView Content Layout Guides are automatically enabled. In iOS versions below iOS 11, there is no Content Layout Guide attribute.

I disabled the Content Layout Guides by selecting the Scroll View, going to the Size Inspector and deselecting 'Content Layout Guides' at the bottom of the first section.

This fixed my issue!